# Sharing environments for Jupyter notebook via github

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook

My company has a rat's nest of a github repo in which multiple Jupyter notebook tutorials are shared with associated requirements.txt files.

I would like to streamline this so that ideally one would need to only open one of these notebooks, easily create the correct environment from the associated requirements.txt file **within the notebook itself**, and then just execute the notebook as normal.

An additional wrinkle is that not all of these dependencies can be installed via conda.  I will need to use pip as the package installer.

Is there a way to do this entirely within a notebook without creating any additional files (ex. environment.yml)?

Comment: Take a look at jupyterhub and poetry

Comment: If your users are in JupyterLab, the https://github.com/thoth-station/jupyterlab-requirements extension may help - though at the cost of having to install and enable that extension.